# Paramiko hanging when encounters missing output

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

Paramiko Script is hanging, attempting to ssh through a list of IP address and execute a few commands to extract information that may or may not be there. For example if i was to implement a uname -a it should reveal the hostname, however if the next server in the list doesn't have a hostname then it seems the script is hanging.

```
import paramiko
import sys
import io
import getpass
import os
import time

# ***** Open Plain Text
f = open("file.txt")

# ***** Read & Store into Variable
hn=(f.read().splitlines())
f.close()

# ***** Credentials 
username =  raw_input("Please Enter Username: ")
password =  getpass.getpass("Please Enter Passwod: ")


# ***** SSH
client=paramiko.SSHClient()
def connect_ssh(hn):
    try:
        client.load_system_host_keys()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect(hn, 22, username, password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)

        print 'Connection Attempting to: '+(hn)
        channel = client.get_transport().open_session()
        channel.invoke_shell()


        #print "CMD
        #channel.send("CMD"+"\n")
        channel.send("command"+"\n")
        CMD = (channel.recv(650000))
        print (CMD)


    except Exception, e:
        print '*** Caught exception: %s: %s' % (e.__class__, e)
    try:
        channel.close()
    except:
        pass

# *****Create Loop through input.txt
for x in hn:
    connect_ssh(x)
```

Comment: What line of code is it hanging on? What happens if you leave it alone? Does it eventually time out or just keep hanging?

Comment: Well, it pulls the first ip information which in this example is uname, however the second ip within the list it hangs at any line after "print 'Connection Attempting to: '+(hn)"                                                                                                                                   if you leave it alone it just hangs, the second IP doesn't have have a host name in this context. So i don't think it's handling the exception at all.